# Template context for Angular components and RouterModule

Tags: angular, angular2-template, template-context

I'm learning Angular and trying to understand how `RouterModule` works with other modules. Say I have a simple `AppModule` as follows.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { MainComponent } from "./main/main.component";
import { FeatureComponent } from "./feature/feature.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: MainComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "feature",
    component: FeatureComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Neither `MainComponent` or `FeatureComponent` are declared in the declarations property of any AppModule but this code still works. What's going on here?

I'm reading [this article](https://angularexperts.io/blog/angular-template-context) about template contexts in Angular. So in this case am I correct in understanding that these components don't have a template context since they are not declared in any module and thus will only be able to support standard HTML/CSS/JS and not the typical features you would get in an Angular component?

Now say I want to create a `WidgetComponent` that in used in both `MainComponent` and `FeatureComponent`. If I just add `WidgetComponent` to the declarations of `AppModule` I get an error in the other components saying "app-widget is not a known element".

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, WidgetComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> 'app-widget' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-widget' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-widget' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

This makes sense as neither `MainComponent` or `FeatureComponent` are declared in `AppModule` where `WidgetComponent` is declared so again they are not in the same template context. Is my understanding of this correct?

To fix this I can declare all three components in `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WidgetComponent,
    MainComponent,
    FeatureComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

...or create a separate modules for the components and import them into one another.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [WidgetComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [WidgetComponent],
})
export class WidgetModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, WidgetModule],
})
export class MainModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [FeatureComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, WidgetModule],
})
export class FeatureModule{}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But in this 2nd solution I don't need to import any of the other modules into `AppModule` I can simply pass the component classes directly to the `RouterModule`. So what I understand from this is the template context of a component is defined simply by the module where it is declared. Is that right?

Comment: Don't know, but for angular pages you should just use [lazy-loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#create-a-feature-module-with-routing) from day 1